# Conditionally format a string in a for-each loop

Tags: powershell, for-loop, variables

This is my scenario:

I have an API that I'm calling via Powershell, the payload is a JSON file, this API needs to be called multiple times and each time, the payload is slightly different (think adding items to a list).

Here's an example of the JSON template.

```
$JSONpaylod = @"
{
  "Config":
  {
  "address": $variable1,
  "authPassword": $variable2,
  "authUsername": $variable3}
}
"@
```

Because it needs to be done multiple times, I'm going to use a For-Each loop, e.g:

```
For-each($_.item in $list){
Do things, then call the API}
```

However, where I'm stuck is that based on the current item in $list, I want to update $variable1, $variable2 and so on based on a lookup.

Is there an elegant way to do this in PowerShell? One thought is that in my Hash table for $list, to have it like this:

```
Item, var1, var2, var3  
1, 23, 1111, admin  
2, 10, 1234, admin
```

but it seems like that would be clunky to have

```
$variable1 = $_.var1 etc.
```

Is there a better way to do this, or am I overthinking this?

Comment: In a parallel vein, I have written a simple csv template engine that copies the csv data into variables of the same name before calling Expand-String to expand the template.  It's generic.  You can download it from www.github.com/dcressey/Expand-Csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to use a CSV as input and construct objects that follow the structure of your Json payload then from there you can use `ConvertTo-Json` to convert them into a Json string. The benefit from doing this is that `ConvertTo-Json` handles the escaping of characters that must be escaped in a Json string, i.e. `"`, `\`, `/` and so on.

```bash
$csv = @'
var1, var2, var3
23, 1111, admin
10, 1234, admin
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

foreach($item in $csv) {
    $payload = [pscustomobject]@{
        Config = [pscustomobject]@{
            address      = $item.var1
            authPassword = $item.var2
            authUsername = $item.var3
        }
    } | ConvertTo-Json

    # do stuff with payload
}
```

As an example, the following would fail exactly where the `"` would be interpolated (line 3, position 20.).

> Conversion from JSON failed with error: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: b. Path 'Config.address', line 3, position 20.

```bash
$item = 'foo"bar'

@"
{
  "Config": {
    "address": "$item"
  }
}
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json
```

And this would work:

```bash
[pscustomobject]@{
    Config = [pscustomobject]@{
        address = 'foo"bar'
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: This was the solution I went with in the end - thanks for that.

Comment: @TheDemonLord glad it was helpful. Note that with CSV as input, all values on each property will be strings, if you need your Json string to parse values as other type, for example if `$item.var1` should be an integer, you can use the `-as` operator while constructing the objects: `address = $item.var1 -as [int]`